# Android dalvik error for few users (Android Version 4.4)

Tags: android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

Some of the app users are getting this error message and the application is crashed. This error log is from Google Console. All these errors are happening with Android version 4.4. Any suggestion on how to solve this one?

Here is the gradle setup. My app is not very complex one. It has Admob library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.app1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "APP")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

### compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' }

```
Today, 4:49 AM on app version 34
Samsung Galaxy Grand2 (ms013g), 1536MB RAM, Android 4.4
Report 32 of 2,511

    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5256)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:4847)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4730)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:172)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1368)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5653)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5241)
```